# State update does not work in React-Native on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, expo

I have some code, where I have pairs of images, and they are all in a swipeable horizontal Gallery. Now when you click the upper of both images, the images should kind off switch, so what I do is, I set isImage2Active as a state, and then just switch the sources of both of them. On iOS it works perfect and completely smooth, but on Android it nearly does not work at all. If you tap it a lot, it might change, but that's obviously not the behavior I want.

So I have an Images component, which is the described swipeable horizontal Gallery

```
const Images = () => {

            const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
            const swiperRef = useRef(null);

            return (
                <>

                    <FlashList
                        data={item.posts}
                        horizontal={true}
                        pagingEnabled={true}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                        estimatedItemSize={350}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <GalleryImage item={item} />
                                </>
                            );
                        }}
                    />
                    {currentPage !== 2 && (
                        <>
                            <Pressable
                                style={{
                                    flex: 1,
                                    backgroundColor: "white",
                                    flexDirection: "row",
                                    zIndex: 1,
                                }}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 2);
                                }}
                            >
                                <Image
                                    style={{
                                        position: "absolute",
                                        bottom: 20,
                                        right: 20,
                                        width: 60,
                                        height: 80,
                                        zIndex: 1,
                                        borderRadius: 15,
                                        borderWidth: 1.5,
                                        borderColor: "black",
                                    }}
                                    source={item.photoUrl2}
                                    blurRadius={100}
                                />
                            </Pressable>
                        </>
                    )}
                    <Pressable
                        style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            backgroundColor: "white",
                            flexDirection: "row",
                            zIndex: 1,
                        }}
                        onPress={switchToMatch}
                    >
                        <Image
                            style={{
                                position: "absolute",
                                bottom: 20,
                                left: 20,
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                zIndex: 1,
                                borderRadius: 50,
                            }}
                            source={
                                showMatchPost
                                    ? "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/2c/86/be/2c86be60d12339b29609532bcbdf6895.jpg"
                                    : "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/63/3e/c1/633ec1cf306c5ec2bc4e37d1ff6afa83.jpg"
                            }
                        />
                    </Pressable>
                </>
            );
        };
```

And then inside I have the Image component, and when I tap the upper image inside the Pressable component it should trigger handleImagePress and then change setIsImage2Active, then switch the sources of the images, but it does not really work on Android, it works 1 out of 20 times, and only if you tap it like crazy. Is this a performance issue, or is it something about the Pressable component? I am really frustrated right now.

```
const GalleryImage = React.memo(({ item }) => {

    const [isImage2Active, setIsImage2Active] = useState(false);
    const [showMatchPost, setShowMatchPost] = useState(false);

    const handleImagePress = useCallback(() => {
        setIsImage2Active(!isImage2Active);
    }, [isImage2Active]);

    const switchToMatch = useCallback(() => {
        setShowMatchPost(!showMatchPost);
    }, [showMatchPost]);


    return (
        <>
            <View
                style={{
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    flex: 1,
                    width: 390, // or use a fixed value if you prefer
                }}
            >
                <Pressable
                    style={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        zIndex: 1000,
                    }}
                    onPress={handleImagePress}
                >
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            position: "absolute",
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            width: 100,
                            height: 150,
                            zIndex: 1,
                            borderRadius: 15,
                        }}
                        source={
                            isImage2Active
                                ? showMatchPost
                                    ? item.photoUrl2
                                    : item.photoUrl1
                                : showMatchPost
                                    ? item.photoUrl1
                                    : item.photoUrl2
                        }
                    />
                </Pressable>
                <Image
                    style={{ width: "100%", height: 390 }}
                    source={
                        isImage2Active
                            ? showMatchPost
                                ? item.photoUrl1
                                : item.photoUrl2
                            : showMatchPost
                                ? item.photoUrl2
                                : item.photoUrl1
                    }
                    blurRadius={0}
                />
            </View>
        </>

    )
})
```

I tried putting it in a FlatList (FlashList by Spotify, that should improve performance), because previously I had a PagerView and mapped all Posts, then handleImagePress would change all images to isImage2Active that are part of the Gallery, but now I switched to individual Image components, so only one Image should update, but the performance has improved by 0.

```
const [isImage2Active, setIsImage2Active] = useState(false);
const [showMatchPost, setShowMatchPost] = useState(false);

const handleImagePress = useCallback(() => {
    setIsImage2Active(!isImage2Active);
}, [isImage2Active]);

return (
    <>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 100, height: 100, }}>
            <Pressable style={{
                flex: 1, width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 20
            }} onPress={handleImagePress}>
                <Image style={{
                    flex: 1, width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 20
                }}
                    source={isImage2Active ? "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/f3/7c/ff/f37cfff4e11964b9ae846f901965cc5e.jpg" : "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/fa/84/56/fa84564e78db58b48e10a245bb7fdb56.jpg"} />
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    </>
)
```

I have also created another screen where I tested this with just 1 image, and it works perfectly, but inside of the FlatList, there are extreme performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimise your FlatList performance and your image also. As I can see, they are being fetched from a remote URL, try to optimise there either by preloading images or use some optimised image libraries like `react-native-fast-image` to better load your images.